# Convert Eclipse Plugin Projects to Eclipse RCP Application

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-juno

I have a list of different plugins (that constitute one Eclipse plugin together) and i want to create an Eclipse 4 Juno RCP application from them. What are the steps to do that?

Thanks in advance and kind regards!

Answer (score 4):

You can basically just follow the instructions of Lars Vogel [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseRCP/article.html#plugin_creatinge4).

He's describing how to **convert** an Eclipse plug-in **into an Eclipse 4 application**.

*Like tkotisis added:* After you created the application as described by Vogella, you need to add all plug-ins to one or more features. Then include them in your product configuration.

Comment: I'm looking for another description of the process than Lars Vogellas
since he is talking about a single plugin ...

Comment: @MichaelKornmann The process is almost identical. Just add all plug-ins to one or more features, which you include in your product configuration.

Comment: I am following vogella now but when i try to launch my app i get the following error:  "Application "org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.E4Application" could not be found in the registry. The applications available are: org.eclipse.equinox.app.error. "